# Mean of a numeric variable table with a factor

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. I have one numeric variable and one factor with two levels. I made a table of them.

How do I know the mean value of the numeric for each level?

Comment: Reproducible example dataset, please.

Comment: Seems like you need `dplyr` `df%>%group_by(LVL)%>%summarise(M=mean(numeric ))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets make a dataframe with name DF. x1 - numeric, x2 - factor

> DF

```
   x1 x2
 1  1  a
 2  2  b
 3  3  a
 4  4  b
 5  5  a
 6  6  b

> requires(dplyr)
> DF <- DF%>%group_by(x2)%>%summarise(avg = mean(x1))
```